# How To Manage User Identity Via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, saas

I run a [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) that allows free trials. Basically if you register you get a few dollars worth of free services immediately. I have been determining new users based on IP address alone and it has worked well for the first few months. Now people are finally catching on that it is trivially easy to change their IP address and scam me out of free trial bonuses.

What I want to do is basically create a hash of all possible javascript browser variables and store it in a MySQL database.

If I notice that the same browser hash has signed up for a free trial 10 out of the previous 100 registrations... I will not enable a free trial bonus to that account.

Where do I even start? (Where can I find a list of all javascript browser variable settings like window size, operating system, browser and version number, country, language etc...? Or does jquery offer something like this already?)

I have thought about implementing phone verification via twilio... but that would cost me money, cost my users money, and ultimately lead to fewer free trials.

**EDIT: THE GOAL HERE IS TO LIMIT FRAUDULENT ACTIVITY AS MUCH AS POSSIBLE, AND NOT HINDER REAL ACTIVITY IN THE SLIGHTEST!**

Sure this solution is not perfect, but added with the others I already have it will help. I am willing to accept some loss, but would like to limit it as much as possible.

Comment: Why don't you just implement an authentication mechanism? It's also trivial to switch the browser, or change browser settings.

Comment: @JBNizet : I have thought about implementing phone verification via twilio... but that would cost me money, cost my users money, and ultimately lead to fewer free trials. Requiring facebook, twitter, google logins, etc... is also a deterrent. The goal here is to limit fraud as best as possible, but not hinder regular users at all. I think combining IP verification, with browser fingerprinting is a decent solution. I just need some tips on how to get started.

Comment: Now that I have understood your problem, asking for an email address at registration time and send a registration code by email is a common practice, and could discourage some cheaters. But in the end, if your software is freely usable somehow, a cheater will always find a way to cheat. You could also discourage cheaters by making the free trial more cumbersome to use, or by making your app interesting only if you always keep the same identity.

Comment: That is what I currently do. I require email address verification and make sure we have never seen that IP address before. Sure, some people get around it, but the more ways to block them out, the better. No? re: "making the free trial more cumbersome to use" that is not an option in my books and never will be. If I have to pay out the nose due to fraudsters so be it. I will not resort to limiting my honest customers in any way.

Comment: Though you might work around somethings that are complex, I guess you will land up implementing an account management software (Which I would suggest to start off now). Even dice is similar to your situation, they suggest their customers to use one computer but it will ask to login with account credentials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you might want to do is take a look at browser finger printing http://panopticlick.eff.org/

Although this is not fool proof by any means if you mix it with cookies and the users IP address you should get something that works for most users.

**Updated**
If the idea is to limit fraudulent activity I would implement a SMS based code, similar to how Gmail works. You have to enter your mobile number to get the free trail, If you buy SMS's in bulk you should be able to get them for about 2p each, and its easy to implment just find a SMS supplier with a API.

Although you can use the technique above it is overly complex and still wont be fool proof, and can easily be worked around.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. "Fingerprint the browser's settings." Thank you for that terminology! All of those variables listed in that URL are a great start for me. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if I register in each of the 10+ browsers I have on my machine?

Comment: As I just commented to Tadeck... I would hope to find some set of fairly unique variables that were fairly difficult to change. Yes, it's a tradeoff. One person might be able to get away with using the 10+ browsers that are available, but my goal is only to minimize the threat, as I know I can never truly eradicate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is really **unreliable**.

### Problem

If anything changes (for example the browser is updated, not mentioning it can be just switched), your hash will not be matched and the same person will be able to start the trial again.

Same problem when you store some **session / cookie data** - the cookies can be cleaned (and cookies usually store identifiers for sessions).

### Solution

The problem you are facing can be solved probably only by **registration** - you can simplify this as much as possible by using [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) and allowing people to sign up using their existing accounts from other providers (Google, Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin etc.)

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem. The problem is... I have certain individuals using 1 computer to register 100s of accounts within minutes. If I could detect certain unique settings of their browser... I could weed out the few bots who are signing up a mile a minute.

Comment: @darkAdPitch: I think you misunderstand my solution :) These individuals will not be able to sign up tens of times unless they have tens of legitimate accounts on other services. For other users it should not be a problem to click a few times and quickly signup using their own account. And if you are really dealing with bots, you are out of luck - bots can fake the headers of HTTP requests and you may see them as different browsers, with different data (eg. browser version, operating system, screen resolution) changing with every request. OAuth is really a viable option.

Comment: Requiring facebook, twitter, google logins, etc... is also a deterrent. The goal here is to limit fraud as best as possible, but not hinder regular users at all. I think combining IP verification, with browser fingerprinting is a decent solution. I just need some tips on how to get started. It is a well known fact in the startup community that requiring alternate logins is a bad idea/deterrent to user registrations. I have plenty of friends who do not and refuse to use facebook, for example. Also, I do not want to rely on their verification methods, I want an in house solution.

Comment: @darkAsPitch: Ok, I get your point. From my point of view depending on in-house verification methods will scare away people more than depending on their existing account's verification (they can decide what data they share).

Comment: The only in house verification method we currently offer is verifying your email address and making sure we have never seen that IP address before. Most customers don't even know we verify ip addresses. And they wouldn't know that we verified browser fingerprints, either. I only see it as an extra possibility to deter determined fraudsters, not the ultimate solution. Any suggestions concerning my original question?

Comment: @darkAsPitch: No, I have no suggestions at the moment, as bots can change virutally any clien-side setting (or make it appear as different), even some legitimate browsers are able to appear as different browser to the website they connect. The problem is bots can change it, but legitimate users usually do not do it. Are you sure these "fraudulent" requests do not differ with such settings as browser name / version? Did you check it? If they did not change, your solution based on hashing some settings may have some chance (until they realize it and begin altering them between requests).

Comment: I am almost certain they change the browser type/version... it is other aspects that are not so easily changeable that I am after... such as screen resolution, operating system, etc... perhaps if I find the right combination of unique but difficult to change items, I could create a useful hash. Looks like I will have to write up my own topic on this subject since there is virtually nothing out there at the moment. I will report back here if and when I do. Thanks for the chat.

Comment: @darkAsPitch: I would be happy to see some reliable solution based on client side values, so if you find anything at least moderately reliable, please post it somewhere here. I really doubt that such client-side anti-bot solution exists, though.

Comment: OAuth is meant for attracting customers who already have login credentials with a provider and will go away if we do not provide them some "VIP treatment". It is not meant for our own account holders.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to uniquely identify a person in javascript. This is something that is generally impossible to do on the web - partly by design, to maintain anonymity. The best you can do here is set a cookie, and check for the cookie when the user try's to change their IP address. 
They will always be able to clear their cookies, but that's about all you can do.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem. The problem is... I have certain individuals using 1 computer to register 100s of accounts within minutes. If I could detect certain unique settings of their browser... I could weed out the few bots who are signing up a mile a minute. YES... they will always be able to change their cookies, but most of these theives are probably not smart enough to change their operating system or display settings every few seconds... especially if they do not know I am looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing captcha ?
It would not be a deterrent against users willing to create multiple accounts manually but would definitely defeat the bots creating hundred of accounts in minutes.
I like recaptcha :
http://www.google.com/recaptcha, it's free, it has solutions for people that are visually impaired and it help digitising books.